# Is MVC an overkill for a chess CLI game?

Tags: java, design-patterns, console, mvc, chess

I am working on a CLI chess game that only involves 2 human players, I decided to make it follow the MVC architecture to ensure separation of concern and to make the possibility of a GUI/web integration easier to achieve.

Here is the package diagram:

[image]

The view only has the `View` class that draws the board and the pieces, the controller takes input from the user and communicates with the `Game` class inside of the `game` package, which is more of a Facade class, which is inside the model.

ChessGame (controller) class:

```
package controller;

import model.game.Game;
import view.View;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChessGame {
    private final Game game;
    private final View view;
    public ChessGame() {
        this.game = new Game();
        this.view = new View();
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        view.draw(game.getBoard());
        initializePlayers(sc);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(game.getCurrentPlayer() + " turn!");
                if (game.playerIsInCheck()) {
                    System.out.println("Check! Protect the king.");
                }
                System.out.println("Enter a command:");
                game.executeCommand(sc.nextLine());
                if (game.pawnPromoted()) {
                    handlePromotion(sc);
                }
                //If player is still in check after executing the move, undo the move.
                if (game.playerIsInCheck()) {
                    game.undoCommand();
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("King is still in check, undoing last move...");
                }
                view.draw(game.getBoard());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Try again.");
                continue;
            }
            game.setWhitePlayerTurn(!game.isWhitePlayerTurn());
            game.setBlackPlayerTurn(!game.isBlackPlayerTurn());
        }
    }
    public void handlePromotion(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("PROMOTION!");
        System.out.println("Choose a piece to promote to:");
        System.out.println("1)Queen\n2)Rook\n3)Bishop\n4)Knight");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        game.promote(choice);
    }
    private void initializePlayers(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Enter white player name: ");
        String whitePlayerName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter black player name: ");
        String blackPlayerName = sc.nextLine();
        game.setWhitePlayerName(whitePlayerName);
        game.setBlackPlayerName(blackPlayerName);
    }
}
```

`draw` method inside of `View`:

```
    public void draw(Board board) {
    int rows = Board.ROWS;
    int columns = Board.COLUMNS;
    String borderColor = ANSI_RED;
    System.out.println(borderColor + "   ===================" + ANSI_RESET);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        System.out.print(((columns + 1) - i) + borderColor + " || " + ANSI_RESET);
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
            Square currentSquare = new Square(j, (columns + 1) - i);
            if (board.isSquareOccupied(currentSquare)) {
                printPiece(board.getPieceFromSquare(currentSquare));
            } else {
                System.out.print("- " + ANSI_RESET);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(borderColor + "||" + ANSI_RESET);
    }
    System.out.println(borderColor + "   ===================" + ANSI_RESET);
    System.out.println("\t a b c d e f g h");
}
```

`ANSI_*` are constant variables for color.

I am not going to add code from the model since I am concerned about the architecture and the way the classes communicate, not the logic.

Is this overengineered and an overkill for a CLI application? Also, since we're using DI in `draw` to insert the board, does this make the `view` package dependent on `model`? Is there a way to use `draw` without any DI?

Comment: I might be wrong, but since the view communicates with the controller and doesn't communicate directly with the view, I think this is Model-View-Adapter rather than Model-View-Controller (not that there's anything wrong with that)

Comment: "the view communicates with the controller and doesn't communicate directly with the view", do you mean doesn't communicate directly with the model? Isn't that how MVC is structured?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. And my understanding of MVC is that usually the controller tells the model to update, and then the model tells the view to update, with direct communication between the view and controller usually being fairly limited. But, again, I could be wrong

Comment: To be fair I have found multiple ways on how to implement MVC, my idea was that the model updates the view but indirectly, the controller takes user input, manipulates the data in the model and then sends the new data to the view to render.

Comment: UCI protocol for chess engines is already MVC model, which is a possibility for humans playing